# A/R & A/P in OFX file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, ofx

I'm working on exporting data from an existing accounting system written in C# in house and the goal is to have the data usable in multiple accounting packages. For that we've selected the OFX standard, as the major accounting software will import those files. I've found a few libraries for C# that will import data in OFX format, but none that will export it. I can't find is how accounts receivable and accounts payable are stored in the OFX specification. What is the tag for the A/R & A/P in OFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find is that there is not an specific tag for A/R & A/P, they both have to be stored as normal accounts.